# How to output the value for a key embedded in a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary output that looks like `mydict={'a': {'b': c, 'd': e}}` and I would like to only output the value for b to start. In addition I would like to output the value for each key imbedded

I've tried mydict.'a'.b, mydict.a.b and mydict.b without success

Comment: it is python, not javascript :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is `mydict['a']['b']`

Comment: Got it, thanks alot. To add on, is there a way for me to get all of the values for each key imbedded inside a? And I have a few minutes left before it can be accepted